# Какую web-панель использовать и использовать ли для стека LAMP

Tags: администрирование, веб-сервер, lamp, control-panel

Я только начинающий системный администратор, только учусь. По советам работал только с терминалом, научился ставить сервер, настраивать ftp создавать хосты и так далее. Теперь озадачился веб интерфейсом для управления сервером, какой лучше поставить.

Интерфейс решил поставить для таких задач как настроить крон, резервное купирование и слежением за пространством. Посоветуйте пожалуйста новичку, или может бить интерфейс совсем не нужен?

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: по своему опыту работы в большой конторе, могу сказать, что никакие веб-панели эксплуатация не использует, все через скрипты и консоль. для мониторинга - заббикс, некоторые инженеры для себя ставят графану. кроме того, апач тоже не используется. p.s. почему не рекомендую веб-панели: расслабляет, дополнительная точка слома, может случится так, что панель отвалится, а ssh-ключа нет, пароль забыт и только в ДЦ звонить.

Comment: @strangeqargo ок, понял, значить буду делать все в ручную. Через терминал.

Comment: поизучать веб-панели можете, если придется конечным пользователям настраивать что-нибудь. но зависеть от них - ни в коем случае